# How can I know from list id that it is a list or a library?

Tags: development, list, library

I want to know whether the current list which I have is Custom list or a document library.
How cant I check this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SPList.BaseTemplate` property as shown in sample code below:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[ListGUID];
if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary)
{
    //Document Library
}
else if (list.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.GenericList)
{
    // Custom list
}
```